# Compare two arguments ASM x64

Tags: assembly, compare, arguments, 64-bit, cmp

Someone can tell me how to compare two arguments (`RDI` and `RSI`) in ASM x64 ?

I have a problem on compilation when I use:

```
cmp byte[rdi+rax],byte[rsi+rax]
```

I'm getting an error:

```
"error: invalid combination of opcode and operands"
```

Comment: You can't have two memory operands. Load one into a register first.

Comment: Ok thank you. Like that :?

mov rcx, rdi
cmp byte[rdi+rax],byte[rcx+rax]

I have an error too .. .:(

Comment: Like that: `mov cl, byte[rdi+rax]; cmp cl,byte[rsi+rax]`

Comment: Nice ! Thank you. But can you tell me what the diff between cl and rcx ? (Sorry, I am a new in ASM ^^) cl is for string ans rcx, etc for int ?

Comment: cl is for 8-bit values (characters and small integers); rcx is for 64-bit values (addresses and large integers).

Comment: @Armed9Gagger it may be instructive to look at how ModR/M and SIB bytes work, it may help you understand what kind of operands you can use.

Comment: @EvgenyKluev: Maybe you could post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cmp` instruction, like the majority of x86/x86-64 instructions, allows at most one memory operand. So, to compare contents of two memory locations, you need to load at least one of them into a register:

```
mov cl, byte[rdi+rax]
cmp cl, byte[rsi+rax]
```